# Converting non-ascii characters with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, non-ascii-characters

I want to ask a question about converting text characters to binary numbers in Python.
I wrote a program that convert all ASCII characters and some Turkish characters to binary numbers. 
Below codes are the codes of that convertor program:

```
while True:
    ASCII_characters_dict = {chr(i): "0" + bin(ord(chr(i)))[2:] for i in range(128)}
    for i in ASCII_characters_dict:
        if len(ASCII_characters_dict[i]) == 7:
            ASCII_characters_dict[i] = "0" + ASCII_characters_dict[i]
        elif len(ASCII_characters_dict[i]) == 6:
            ASCII_characters_dict[i] = "00" + ASCII_characters_dict[i]
        elif len(ASCII_characters_dict[i]) == 5:
            ASCII_characters_dict[i] = "000" + ASCII_characters_dict[i]
        elif len(ASCII_characters_dict[i]) == 4:
            ASCII_characters_dict[i] = "0000" + ASCII_characters_dict[i]
        elif len(ASCII_characters_dict[i]) == 3:
            ASCII_characters_dict[i] = "00000" + ASCII_characters_dict[i]
        elif len(ASCII_characters_dict[i]) == 2:
            ASCII_characters_dict[i] = "000000" + ASCII_characters_dict[i]
    Turkish_characters = "çÇöÖüÜ"
    Turkish_characters_dict = {i: bin(ord(i))[2:] for i in Turkish_characters}
    Dictionary = ASCII_characters_dict.copy()
    Dictionary.update(Turkish_characters_dict)
    başlık = "WELCOME TO THE CONVERTOR"
    süs="-"*80
    print("\n{}\n\n{}\n".format(süs, başlık.center(80," ")))
    seçenekler = "1. To convert text to binary, press '1'.\n2. To convert binary to text, press '2'.\n3. To exit the program, press '3'."
    print("{0}\n\n{1}\n\n{0}\n".format(süs, seçenekler))
    while True:
        seçim = input("Select:")
        print("\n{}\n".format(süs))
        if seçim=="1":
            break
        elif seçim=="2":
            break
        elif seçim == "3":
            quit()
        else:
            print("Warning: Please select one of the given numbers.\n")
    while seçim == "1":
        altbaşlık = "Convert Text to Binary"
        print("{}\n\n{}\n".format(altbaşlık.center(80," "), süs))
        text_1 = input("Text:")
        text_2 = ""
        for i in text_1:
            for j in Dictionary:
                if i == j:
                    text_2 += Dictionary[j]
        with open("Text_To_Binary.txt","a") as dosya:
            dosya.write("\n{0}\n\nBinary: {1}\n\n{0}\n".format(süs, text_2))
        print("\n{0}\n\nBinary: {1}\n\n{0}".format(süs, text_2))
        message = "1. To continue converting text to binary, press '1'.\n\n3. To return the main page, press '2'.\n\n3. To exit the program, press '3'."
        print("\n{}\n\n{}".format(message,süs))
        while True:
            yeni_seçim_1 = input("\nSelect:")
            print("\n{}\n".format(süs))
            if yeni_seçim_1 == "1":
                break
            elif yeni_seçim_1 == "2":
                break
            elif yeni_seçim_1 == "3":
                quit()
            else:
                print("Warning: Please select one of the given numbers.")
        if yeni_seçim_1 == "1":
            continue
        elif yeni_seçim_1 == "2":
            break
    while seçim == "2":
        altbaşlık = "Convert Binary to Text"
        print("{}\n\n{}\n".format(altbaşlık.center(80," "), süs))
        text_1 = input("Binary:")
        text_2 = ""
        list_1 = []
        if " " in text_1:
            list_1 = text_1.split()
        elif " " not in text_1:
            for i in range(len(text_1)):
                if i % 8 == 0:
                    text_2 += " "
                text_2 += text_1[i]
            list_1 = text_2[1:].split(" ")
        text_3 = ""
        for i in list_1:
            for j in Dictionary:
                if i == Dictionary[j]:
                    text_3 += j
        with open("Binary_To_Text.txt","a") as dosya:
            dosya.write("\n{0}\n\nText: {1}\n\n{0}\n".format(süs, text_3))
        print("\n{0}\n\nText: {1}\n\n{0}\n".format(süs, text_3))
        message = "1. To continue converting binary to text, press '1'.\n\n3. To return the main page, press '2'.\n\n3. To exit the program, press '3'."
        print("{}\n\n{}".format(message,süs))
        while True:
            yeni_seçim = input("\nSelect:")
            print("\n{}\n".format(süs))
            if yeni_seçim == "1":
                break
            elif yeni_seçim == "2":
                break
            elif yeni_seçim == "3":
                quit()
            else:
                print("Warning: Please select one of the given numbers.")
        if yeni_seçim == "2":
            break
```

This convertor can convert **“çÇöÖüÜ”** characters to binary numbers correctly. I removed the **“şŞğĞıİ”** characters from the Turkish_characters_list because the program can’t convert them correctly.

According to the http://roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp

1. The binary numbers of character **“ş”** is **“001001100010001100110011001101010011000100111011”**
   When i copy this number and write it to the “binary to text” section of the program, the output is displaying as **“& # 351 ;”** <-> (I put spaces between the characters because it is displayed **"ş"**).
   When i type chr(351), the output is displaying the result as character **“ş”**.
2. The binary numbers of character **“ş”** is bin(351) which equals to **“0b101011111”**. But when i write this numbers to the converter, the program is displaying the result as null.
3. The same problem can be seen in **“ŞğĞıİ”** characters. However  **“çÇöÖüÜ”** characters can be converted without problem.

According to the https://www.binarytranslator.com/

1. The binary numbers of character **“ş”** is **“01011111”**. But this numbers belong to the character **"_”**.
2. The same problem can be seen in **“ŞğĞıİ”** characters.

So, one of my questions is about why **“çÇöÖüÜ”**  characters can be converted correctly and **“şŞğĞıİ”** characters can’t be converted correctly? Is there any solution for this problem apart from asciifying the **“şŞğĞıİ”** characters by controlling them after the input step?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All about character sets, encodings. In **ASCII** there are no accented characters, **Latin-1** there is **çÇöÖüÜ** and in Latin-3 I believe all Turkish characters can be given. In general one would use **UTF-8**  (encoding Unicode), with which you could combine any script, Turkish, Arabic and so on. However UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding. Further: `&#351;` and such are HTML numeric entities.

Comment: Hi, in order to make a spesific change in the program. Where should i change the encoding of the characters?

Answer (score -1):

Let me share what i have learned from that example.

First of all, ASCII characters are characters which have 8 digits. 7 of the them represent the binary number of the character, the last digit is equal to "0" which is called "parity bit". (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit)

For example: Character **a**'s binary number is **'1100001'** but usually this number is displayed as **"01100001"**. This displaying is called "Parity check". Parity check is a control type to know whether the binary number is odd or even.

The reason of adding a parity bit to this binary number is while sending to another computer this binary number, there may be an disruption in transferring. The binary number of **"a"** is equal to **97**, which is an odd number. By putting **"0"** parity bit to this number, this number keeps on representing **97**.

So character **"a"** is a number that defined in ASCII. All ASCII characters are 8 bit (means the binary numbers have 8 digits.) But the non-ASCII characters are 16 bit. Let's see why non-ASCII characters are 16 bit.

```
number=ord("a")
#number=97
string=chr(number)
#string="a"
```

The above codes define a string that include only character **"a"**. However when the user want to encode this number with "utf-8" like above:

```
number=ord("a")
#number=97
string=chr(number).encode(encoding="utf-8")
#string=b'a'
len(string)
#1
```

This code will define a string in hex format if after **"b"** character comes **"\x"** characters. Suppose to be the character is **"ç"**:

```
number=ord("ç")
#number=231
string=chr(231).encode(encoding="utf-8")
#string="b'\xc3\xa7'"
len(string)
#2
```

The last value of the string seems a bit weird but it's real value is in it. The value is **"c3a7"** which is a hexadecimal number. The length of the character **"a"** is **1**. It means that this number has 8 digits(bits) and is equal to 1 byte. However the length of the character **"ç"** is 2. It means that this number has 16 digits(bits) and is equal to 2 byte.

So let's look at character **ç**'s binary number:

```
number=int("c3a7",16)
#number=50087
binary_number_of_character_ç=bin(50087)
#binary_number_of_character_ç=1100001110100111
len(binary_number_of_character_ç)
#16
```

So the binary number of **"ç"** is **"1100001110100111"** which is also usually displayed like **"11000011 10100111"**.

If we shall change the whole code structure according to the above information, the codes can be like the below which give no error in displaying non-ascii characters:

```
#-----------------------------IMPORTING Fore and init FUNCTIONS FROM COLORAMA MODULE------------------------------------

from colorama import Fore,init
init(autoreset=True)

#--------------------------------------------DICTIONARY FUNCTION--------------------------------------------------------

def dictionary():
    ascii_dictionary = {chr(i): bin(i)[2:] for i in range(128)}
    for i in ascii_dictionary:
        if len(ascii_dictionary[i]) < 8:
            count = 8 - len(ascii_dictionary[i])
            ascii_dictionary[i] = "".zfill(count) + ascii_dictionary[i]
    non_ascii_dictionary = {chr(i): bin(int(bytes(chr(i).encode(encoding="utf-8")).hex(), 16))[2:10] + " " +
                        bin(int(bytes(chr(i).encode(encoding="utf-8")).hex(), 16))[10:18] for i in range(128, 512)}
    dictionary = ascii_dictionary.copy()
    dictionary.update(non_ascii_dictionary)
    return dictionary

#--------------------------------------------CONVERTER FUNCTIONS--------------------------------------------------------

def convert_text_to_binary():
    text_1 = input("Write A Text:")
    print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "\n{}".format("-" * 80))
    return_value = dictionary()
    list_1 = [return_value[j] for i in text_1 for j in return_value if i == j]
    text_2 = " ".join(list_1)
    print(Fore.RED + "\nOutput: " + Fore.GREEN + "{}\n\n".format(text_2) + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "{}\n".format("-" * 80))
    with open("Text.to_Binary.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write("{0}\nInput: {2}\n\nOutput: {1}\n{0}".format("\n"+"-"*80+"\n", text_2, text_1))


def convert_binary_to_text():
    text_1 = input("Write Binary Numbers:")
    print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "\n{}".format("-" * 80))
    list_1 = text_1.split()
    list_2 = [i for i in list_1 if i.startswith("1")]
    count = 0
    list_3 = []
    while count < len(list_2):
        list_3.append(" ".join(list_2[count:count + 2]))
        count += 2
    list_4 = []
    count = 0
    for i in list_1:
        if i.startswith("0"):
            list_4.append(i)
        elif i.startswith("1"):
            list_1.remove(i)
            list_4.append(list_3[count])
            count += 1
    text_2 = ""
    return_value = dictionary()
    for i in list_4:
        for j in return_value:
            if i == return_value[j]:
                text_2 += j
    print(Fore.RED + "\nOutput: " + Fore.GREEN + "{}\n\n".format(text_2) + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "{}\n".format("-" * 80))
    with open("Binary_to_Text.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write("{0}\nInput: {2}\n\nOutput: {1}\n{0}".format("\n"+"-"*80+"\n", text_2, text_1))

#------------------------------------------STYLING WITH TEXT CLASS------------------------------------------------------

class text():
    def __init__(self,name,style=Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX+"-"*80):
        self.name=name
        self.style=style
    def title(self):
        print("\n{0}\n\n{1}\n\n{0}\n".format(self.style, str(self.name).center(80, " ")))
    def paragraph(self):
        print("{0}\n\n{1}\n".format(self.name, self.style))

#-----------------------------------------------TEXT INSTANCES----------------------------------------------------------

head = text(Fore.RED + "WELCOME TO THE CONVERTER")
sub_head_1 = text(Fore.RED + "CONVERT TEXT TO BINARY")
sub_head_2 = text(Fore.RED + "CONVERT BINARY TO TEXT")
head_options = text(Fore.RED + "1. " + Fore.GREEN + "To convert text to binary, press '1'.\n\n" + 
                    Fore.RED + "2. " + Fore.GREEN + "To convert binary to text, press '2'.\n\n" + 
                    Fore.RED + "3. " + Fore.GREEN + "To exit the program, press '3'.")
sub_head_options = text(Fore.RED + "1. " + Fore.GREEN + "To continue converting, press '1'\n\n" + 
                        Fore.RED + "2. " + Fore.GREEN + "To return the main page, press '2'.\n\n" + 
                        Fore.RED + "3. " + Fore.GREEN + "To exit the program, press '3'.")

#-----------------------------------------------CHOICE FUNCTION---------------------------------------------------------

def choice():
    while True:
        select = input("Select:")
        if select == "1":
            return select
        elif select == "2":
            return select
        elif select == "3":
            quit()
        else:
            print(Fore.RED+"\nWarning: "+Fore.GREEN+"Please select one of the given numbers.\n")
            continue
        if select == "1" or select == "2":
            break

#---------------------------------------BUNDLING PROGRAM PARTS IN FUNCTION----------------------------------------------

def main_program():
    while True:
        head.title()
        head_options.paragraph()
        select = choice()
        while select == "1":
            sub_head_1.title()
            convert_text_to_binary()
            sub_head_options.paragraph()
            new_select = choice()
            if new_select == "2":
                break
        while select == "2":
            sub_head_2.title()
            convert_binary_to_text()
            sub_head_options.paragraph()
            new_select = choice()
            if new_select == "2":
                break

main_program()
```